# How to generate random 64 bit ints with boost random

Tags: c++, boost, boost-random

I'm trying to generate a random 64bit unsigned integer using boost random,
but I'm getting an assertion failure with uniform_int.

```
struct timeval tv;
boost::mt19937 randGen(tval.tv_usec);
boost::uniform_int<> uInt64Dist(0, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > getRand(randGen, uInt64Dist);
uint64_t clock_seq_= getRand();
```

Here is what gets output at line 3.

```
main:/usr/include/boost/random/uniform_int.hpp:48: boost::uniform_int<IntType>::uniform_int(IntType, IntType) [with IntType = int]: Assertion `min_arg <= max_arg' failed.
```

EDIT: Based on your answers, I tried to specify the size with below:

```
boost:uniform_int<uint64_t> ....
```

But I get the following compilation error:

```
spec.cpp: In member function ‘void Specifier::initialize()’:
spec.cpp:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<int> >::variate_generator(boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<long unsigned int>&)’
/usr/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp:97: note: candidates are: boost::variate_generator<Engine, Distribution>::variate_generator(Engine, Distribution) [with Engine = boost::mt19937&, Distribution = boost::uniform_int<int>]
/usr/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp:87: note:                 boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<int> >::variate_generator(const boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<int> >&)
make: *** [spec.o] Error 1
```

EDIT: ok, missed the second instance of boost::uniform_int.  Once I got both of them, it's all go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`uniform_int`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/uniform_int.html) defaults to `int` as the value type. Use the following instead:

```
boost::uniform_int<uint64_t> ...
```

The same goes for the following line:

```
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<uint64_t> > ...
```

Comment: Right, the clue is in the error message: `[with IntType = int]`.

Comment: And `uint64_t` can be found in `<boost/cstdint.hpp>`.

Comment: Sounded promising, but it now doesn't compile.  See my updated question.

Comment: @Matt: Looks like you forgot to change the second instance of `boost::uniform_int`, like the answers reminds. :) (Or maybe I'm wrong.) A `typedef` would be helpful here, so you only needed to change it in one spot.

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify in your declaration of `boost::uniform_int<>` that you are using a 64 bit integer type. Otherwise it [defaults](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/uniform_int.html) to a 32 bit type.

Comment: That sounded promising, but it now doesn't compile.  See updated question.